# How to save only "sheet3" as a CSV file?

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I have some code here that makes you save all the sheets in a workbook as CSVs. Can anyone help me figure out a way for this code to open only sheet 3 "Sheet3" and save it as a CSV?

```
Private Sub CommandButton22_Click() 'Save as CSV
    Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim SaveToDirectory As String

    Dim CurrentWorkbook As String
    Dim CurrentFormat As Long

    CurrentWorkbook = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    CurrentFormat = ThisWorkbook.FileFormat
    ' Store current details for the workbook
    SaveToDirectory = "H:\Test\"
    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Sheets(WS.Name).Copy
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=SaveToDirectory & ThisWorkbook.Name & "-" & WS.Name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
        ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
        ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Next

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=CurrentWorkbook, FileFormat:=CurrentFormat
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You see the `For Each` to the `Next` - that's looping through all the sheets. That's what needs to be modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Raystafarian mentioned, here's the code

```
For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If WS.name= "Sheet3" then
    Sheets(WS.Name).Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=SaveToDirectory & ThisWorkbook.Name & "-" & WS.Name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I am new to programing and am trying to learn how loops work. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Sheets(WS.Name).Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=SaveToDirectory & ThisWorkbook.Name & "-" & WS.Name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
Next
```

with

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet3").SaveAs Filename:=SaveToDirectory & ThisWorkbook.Name & "-" & WS.Name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
```